# NotImplementedError: Invalid returnType with grouped map Pandas UDFs

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

My output_schema for a Pandas UDF contains the following fields:

```
Out[183]: [StructField(id,StringType,true),
 StructField(2018-01-01,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-02,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-03,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-04,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-05,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-06,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-07,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 StructField(2018-01-08,StructType(List(StructField(real,FloatType,true),StructField(imag,FloatType,true))),true),
 ...
```

and is of type:
`Out[185]: pyspark.sql.types.StructType`

What I'm trying to output is a column with an `id` while the rest of the columns are tuples which hold two floats. My code for defining the schema is below and basically defines the `StructType()` tuple for every column which isn't the `id`.

```
fields = []
for f in json.loads(skeleton_schema.json())["fields"]:
  if f["name"] != "id":
    fields.append(StructField(f["name"], StructType([ 
          StructField(FloatType(), True),
          StructField(FloatType(), True)
        ]), True))
  else:
      fields.append(StructField.fromJson(f))
output_schema = StructType(fields)
```

However, when running my UDF I receive a `NotImplementedError` and the output prints my entire schema and says it's not supported. What exactly isn't supported and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After more debugging, I found out that Nested StructTypes are not supported. The supported types are found [here](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html#supported-sql-types).

Comment: You can check also [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html?highlight=pandas_udf#pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf) to see which types are not supported yet.